# RxJava operators or Kotlin chain

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java

I'm refactoring legacy code and I want to know if code below is more efficient than regular RxJava operators chain?

```
Observable.just(collection.getItems().asSequence()
            .filter { it.itemId == null }
            .filter { it.anotherProp == prop }.toList())
```

Thanks

Comment: why not `filter { it.itemId == null || it.anotherProp == prop }`

Comment: @ReneFerrari Yes, it can be like you propose. But the question was is it a good approach to write like this(kotlin chains in just())

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number 1 advantage of Rx is asynchronous execution, and threads changing (if you could say like that). If you do not need it, then it is more efficient to use, what you called Kotlin chains, cause every chain (every method call) in the Rx chain creates new observable, for example:

```
.filter{ ... }
```

results in this method call, which will create `ObservableFilter`

```
@CheckReturnValue
@SchedulerSupport(SchedulerSupport.NONE)
public final Observable<T> filter(Predicate<? super T> predicate) {
    ObjectHelper.requireNonNull(predicate, "predicate is null");
    return RxJavaPlugins.onAssembly(new ObservableFilter<T>(this, predicate));
}
```

Kotlin `.filter{...}` operator on the other hand uses inlined function

```
public inline fun <T> Iterable<T>.filter(predicate: (T) -> Boolean): List<T> {
    return filterTo(ArrayList<T>(), predicate)
}
```

I would say that, the Rx is best pick if you need to change threads or perform some of chain calls asynchronously, or if whole your system is built upon Rx.